# Linux System Programming in C

Tags: c, linux, system

I am wondering what the following code means ...

```
...
{
    const char *etc; = SYSCONF_DIR; 
...
```

I am sorry for not able to address this kind of problem properly,

I really have no idea what to call this ...thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `SYSCONF_DIR`? I'm seeing a syntax error.

Comment: @Kirilenko: most likely a macro. Although yes, there's a syntax error.

Comment: Ignoring the syntax error, it might be related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9038089/portable-access-to-sysconfdir-via-config-h

Comment: nope, I am asking about this programming construct... but I got the answer, thanks still  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above code assings a [macro](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Macros.html) a pointer named `etc`. Your code has a syntax error as of now. Instead of

```
const char *etc; = SYSCONF_DIR;
```

It should be

```
const char *etc = SYSCONF_DIR;
```

I understand that this might not be a very revealing answer, but the level of the depth of an answer is deemed by the quality of the question. You basically took one line of code and asked us what it does. It's like taking a book, pulling out a sentence, showing it to a friend and asking him what book is this from...

EDIT:

A quick search on google of your snipet reavels that its taken from [here](http://books.google.ca/books?id=k_ocKY0iegsC&pg=PA267&lpg=PA267&dq=const%20char%20%2aetc;%20=%20SYSCONF_DIR;&source=bl&ots=VgFOHahEHt&sig=PfHyZ_Fdc1p49unbjKUKkOi0kSI&hl=en#v=onepage&q=const%20char%20%2aetc;%20=%20SYSCONF_DIR;&f=false). I know that as a fact because the syntax error appears in this book as well. A quick look reveals that the MACRO `SYSCONF_DIR` equates to the string `"/etc/"`. Also the book explains quite extensively what that function does...

Comment: haha, thanks. I thought it was some kind of program construct that I never saw. thanks.